Automatically change autofilter based on linked cell
The tl;dr: How do I force an Autofilter script to run when a cell change (induced by another script, not user input) is detected in the I2 cell?
(note: Excel 365, I don't see a specific tag for that one, but feel free to adjust if I missed it!)

I have linked cells on different tabs that change value whenever one of the others changes its value. If you set 5 on one tab, it will change the other cells on the other tabs to that same value. This is an example, from tab1 (the other tabs are currently identical in content and layout, with locally adjusted versions of this script):
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target.Address = Range("F2").Address Then
      Range("A5:E120").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=Range("F1:F2")
   End If
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("I2")) Is Nothing Then
  If Target = Range("I2") Then
    If Sheets("tab2").Range("I2").Value <> Target.Value Then
      Sheets("tab2").Range("I2").Value = Target.Value
    End If
  End If
End If
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("I2")) Is Nothing Then
  If Target = Range("I2") Then
    If Sheets("tab3").Range("I2").Value <> Target.Value Then
      Sheets("tab3").Range("I2").Value = Target.Value
    End If
  End If
End If
End Sub

I'm attempting to filter the rows on two of these tabs based on this value: if set to 5, it should show all rows in column A that contain a value of 5 or less (or 3 or less, or 2 or less etc). I've created a helper column to this effect that checks the value in I2 and compares column A values:
=IF(A5<=$I$2,"yes","no")

The idea is that anything with 'yes' will show, and anything with 'no' will be hidden.
Currently I'm manually using AutoFilter on each tab, but I'd like to automate the filter changes. Although I'm quite advanced in tying complex spreadsheets together using the built in formulas, with vba I'm still quite new.
This seems promising (also featured above): https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-autofilter-rows-based-on-cell-values-in-excel , which doesn't seem to use the full AutoFilter pulldown menus, but works none the less:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Updated By Nirmal
   If Target.Address = Range("F2").Address Then
      Range("A5:E120").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=Range("F1:F2")
   End If
End Sub

This takes the value of E2 and hides the rows with a value in the column with the header that matches E1. The AutoFilter pulldown menus aren't available, but this is fine as the filtering is the part that matters.
What I'm running into is that this script doesn't seem to pick up on linked cell changes, only after direct user input. So then you'd have to do an edit on each tab again, which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid (i.e. change value in one place, have filters change everywhere)...

If I understand correctly, I would either 1) update the IF statement in the second macro to include an OR statment to look at I2, 2) embed the AdvanceFilter option into the appropriate place in your first macro.

Have you considered the use of a table with slicers

@gns100 looks like that solved it, thanks :) Changing the pulldown menu based value on any of the three sheets autofilters all three. I'll add it as an answer.

Even though the test sheet works perfectly, applying this one in my production sheet suddenly hides ALL but row 1, even though the range it would apply to, doesn't start until row 5... What would cause this kind of behaviour?

Looks like the range needs to be preceded by a completely empty row... Hopefully that fixes it :)

The trick is in adding another check for that second cell (see the second line below):
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target.Address = Range("F2").Address Or Target.Address = Range("I2").Address Then
      Range("A5:E120").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=Range("F1:F2")
   End If
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("I2")) Is Nothing Then
  If Target = Range("I2") Then
    If Sheets("tab2").Range("I2").Value <> Target.Value Then
      Sheets("tab2").Range("I2").Value = Target.Value
    End If
  End If
End If
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("I2")) Is Nothing Then
  If Target = Range("I2") Then
    If Sheets("tab3").Range("I2").Value <> Target.Value Then
      Sheets("tab3").Range("I2").Value = Target.Value
    End If
  End If
End If
End Sub

Slight variants of this script (changing 'tab1' and 'tab2') are now in place in each of the three tabs. Changing the value via the pulldown menu on any of the tabs now results in the autofilter being applied to all three tabs automatically.

Thanks to gns100 for pointing me in the right direction!
EDIT: The cells directly above the range (in this case A3:E3) need to be empty, or the filter will hide everything.
